# Using spark's MLLib routines with pandas dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a pretty big data set (~20GB) stored on disk as Pandas/PyTables HDFStore, and I want to run random forests and boosted trees on it. Trying to do it on my local system takes forever, so I was thinking of farming it out to a spark cluster I have access to and instead using MLLib routines.

While I have managed to load the pandas dataframe as an spark dataframe, I'm a little confused about how to use this in MLLib routines. I'm not too familiar with MLLib and it seems that it accepts only LabeledPoint data types.

I would appreciate any ideas / pointers / code that explain how to use (pandas or spark) dataframes as input to MLLib algorithms - either directly or indirectly, by converting to supported types.

Thanks.

Comment: I personally haven't worked with mlib yet, but i did come across this notebook about pyspark and there's a section on mlib  http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/tdhopper/rta-pyspark-presentation/blob/master/slides.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the `DataFrame` to an `RDD[LabeledPoint]`. Note a `LabeledPoint` is just a `(label: Double, features: Vector)`. Consider a mapping routine that grabs values from each row:

```
val rdd = df.map { row =>
  new LabeledPoint(row(0), DenseVector(row.getDouble(1),..., row.getDouble(n)))
}
```

This will return an `RDD[LabeledPoint]` which you can input into a `RandomForest.trainRegressor(...)`, for example. Have a look at the [`DataFrame` API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) for details.

Comment: Great, go ahead and accept the answer so it is documented

Comment: how would you do that in python ?

Answer (score -1):

y_train,X_train is in pandas dataframe, to convert that in mllib input data format

1. convert into numpy array

```
y_train=np.array(y_train)
X_train=np.array(X_train)
```

2. convert in rdd data format

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
train_data=[]
for i in range(X_train.shape[0]):                                                                   
          train_data.append( LabeledPoint(y_train[i],X_train[i]))
```

3. Parallelize it

```
train_data_rdd=sparkContext.parallelize(train_data)

{for spark context ->
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('pandasToSparkDF').getOrCreate()

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .getOrCreate()
sparkContext=spark.sparkContext
}

model = GradientBoostedTrees.trainRegressor(train_data_rdd,categoricalFeaturesInfo={}, numIterations=3)
```